# Any ideas when Firefox is likely to implement lengthAdjust and textLength?

Tags: javascript, svg

Any ideas when Firefox is likely to implement lengthAdjust andtextLength?..... i am working svg application. lengthAdjust and textLength working fine in chrome but not working in fire fox .

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 500 300" version = "1.1">
     <defs>
         <path id="s3" d="M 10,90 Q 100,15 200,70" />
     </defs>
     <g>
         <text font-size = "20">
             <textPath xlink:href="#s3" textLength="205">
                Short text</textPath>
         </text>
         <use xlink:href="#s3" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
     </g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: yes i want to join..

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of a different feature.

Answer (score 1):

This is implemented in Firefox but only for text elements (not for textPath or tspan) in this case that's OK though as you can just move the attribute to the text element.

```html
    <svg viewBox = "0 0 500 300" version = "1.1">
         <defs>
             <path id="s3" d="M 10,90 Q 100,15 200,70" />
         </defs>
         <g>
             <text font-size = "20"  textLength="205">
                 <textPath xlink:href="#s3">
                    Short text</textPath>
             </text>
             <use xlink:href="#s3" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
         </g>
     </svg>
```

There is a [bug for textPath/tspan support open](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=890692) should you wish to contribute to extend it.

Comment: thank you it workin on fire fox but not working IE.you have  any solution for IE

Comment: That's not the question you asked. If you have another question, best ask it separately.